# How can I change an element in a matrix in Maple?

Tags: maple

The question is:

How can I change an element  in a matrix in Maple?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is certainly possible. (It's one of the primary properties of a Matrix, it is a mutable data structure. ie. its entries can be changed.)

If you have assigned a Matrix to the name `A`, then you can change the entry in the 4th row and 5th column by using normal assignment:

```
A[4,5] := 17.34;
```

For more on manipulating Matrices, Vectors, and Arrays, see the [rtable_indexing Help page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=rtable_indexing)

Note that `Matrix` is different from `matrix`, the latter of which is now deprecated.